# Ошибка в коде. Делаю регистрацию на сайте

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Ошибка в коде. Подскажите где она и обьясните?
Пытаюсь сделать регистрацию на сайте.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","game");
$mysqli->query ("SETNAMES 'utf8'");
$login=$_POST["login"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`,`password`,`money`)VALUES('$login','$password','"1000"')");
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: не знаю что за ошибка так как Вы не скинули её код, но предположу что так указывать не правильно ' "1000" '. Таким образом указываются переменные языка которые необходимо объединить со строкой. Вы можете указать так $login и $password, использовав конкатенацию. '".$login."' Ну а 1000 должна быть просто строкой

Comment: А так же Ваш код подвержен sql injection, все переменные в sql запросах надо экранировать

Comment: я уже убрал 100. Уже нету ошибки. Но не записываеться в базу. Почему?

Comment: Потому что после скобки кавычка бессмысленная.

Comment: какая именно скобка бессмысленная?

Comment: @МаркоМідик сделайте var_dump("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`,`password`,`money`)VALUES('$login','$password', '1000')");  (в общем Ваш новый запрос). Далее то что выведет скопируйте в sql phpmyadmin и выполните запрос прям там. Если что-то не верно, то phpmyadmin напишет Вам ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Проверяйте ошибки mysql на всех этапах работы. Для этого есть `$mysqli->error`

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.error.php

Как должен примерно выглядеть ваш код:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","","game");

/* Проверить соединение */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Соединение не удалось: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$result = $mysqli->query ("SETNAMES 'utf8'");
/* Проверить смену кодировки */
if (!$result) {
    printf("Сообщение ошибки: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

$login=$_POST["login"];
$password=$_POST["password"];
$result = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login`,`password`,`money`)VALUES('$login','$password','"1000"')");

 /* Проверить запрос */
 if (!$result) {
     printf("Сообщение ошибки: %s\n", $mysqli->error);
 }
    $mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: Сообщение ошибки: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SETNAMES 'utf8'' at line 1 Сообщение ошибки: Unknown column 'login' in 'field list' Вот такая ошибка вылезла. Что значит?

Comment: 1)  Ошибка при установке кодировки: SETNAMES - пишется в два слова SET NAMES
2) Ошибка при запросе. Пишет что нет поля login